# how to solve this pythonanywhere error , i tried many time

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pythonanywhere, devenv

```
2024-01-06 15:41:00,849: Error running WSGI application
2024-01-06 15:41:00,854: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'officialthiruth.settings'
2024-01-06 15:41:00,854:   File "/var/www/fathu856_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 10, in <module>
2024-01-06 15:41:00,855:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2024-01-06 15:41:00,855: 
2024-01-06 15:41:00,855:   File "/home/fathu856/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2024-01-06 15:41:00,855:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2024-01-06 15:41:00,855: 
2024-01-06 15:41:00,856:   File "/home/fathu856/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
2024-01-06 15:41:00,856:     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2024-01-06 15:41:00,856: 
2024-01-06 15:41:00,856:   File "/home/fathu856/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 89, in __getattr__
2024-01-06 15:41:00,856:     self._setup(name)
2024-01-06 15:41:00,856: 
2024-01-06 15:41:00,856:   File "/home/fathu856/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in _setup
2024-01-06 15:41:00,856:     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2024-01-06 15:41:00,857: 
2024-01-06 15:41:00,857:   File "/home/fathu856/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 190, in __init__
2024-01-06 15:41:00,857:     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2024-01-06 15:41:00,857: ***************************************************
2024-01-06 15:41:00,857: If you're seeing an import error and don't know why,
2024-01-06 15:41:00,857: we have a dedicated help page to help you debug: 
2024-01-06 15:41:00,858: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/
2024-01-06 15:41:00,858: ***************************************************
```

[displaying like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/189gT.jpg)

Comment: OK, you posted your error details, but don't you think you should [edit] your question and post your code that causes this error?

Comment: Also, the error message has a link to the help page you should visit: [https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/)